# Why am I getting these strange artifacts when importing an MDD file?

Tags: import

So, I'm trying to import a `.mdd` animation from C4D to Blender.

**What it should look like:**

[image]

**What I'm getting:**
The animation is here, but the normals are messed up.

Strange artifacts:

[image]

The `.mdd` was imported using mesh deformer. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

The user M.O.Z.G on render.ru has solved this problem for us.

[image]

[image]